# Continuous Media Recording separated into different files of same size

Tags: android

Currently I am using the MediaRecorder API to do voice recording. Below is the code snippet used:

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(filepath);
mRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000);
try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
    mRecorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Using the above code, which I have tested, it is possible to record an audio file which is 5Kb in size and subsequently the recording stops.

What I want to do is to have continous recording and it will be saved as 5Kb files until I call the following code:

```
mRecorder.stop();
mRecorder.reset();
mRecorder.release();
```

Is it possible? Currently, once 5Kb is reached, the recording stops altogether.

Comment: Any idea how? I tried using MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED but could not make it work.

Comment: why u put max file size?? u want only up to 5 kb file

Comment: if u want continuous recording just comment that line and record

Comment: I was testing with 5Kb. Will change it to bigger size. The issue is if continuous recording the file may get too big and it will be difficult to upload. That's why want to break it into smaller size while recording.

Comment: there is nothing problem man!! u have to upload file up to 5mb and etc... u don't bother about file size just record the file continuously.. there is any problem in recording tell me.. where is the problem..

Comment: Recording has no problem. But for example my output file is 100mb how do I break it down to smaller file size? Because I want to upload smaller files.

Comment: the record file has never reach to that size.. u have to provide the limit for user just for 2mins or 5 mins..  for any recording user 2 to 5 mins is so getting bored...

Comment: if u want to send smaller files division is not possible.. u just record some file and send and next time u have to record and send that's the way i think......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SubbaReddy PolamReddy Thanks for the tips. What u say makes sense, it will be much easier to just set the file limit using setMaxFileSize(filesizeInBytes).

Answer (score 0):

I use different approach. After every 1 minutes, I restart the Recording process, like this:

```
int RestartAfterSeconds=60;

Boolean recording =false;
private void Stop_Record(){
    if (recording) {
       recording=false;
       // ................
       // ................
       // ................
       // your codes here
       // ................
       // ................
       // ................
    }
}

public void Start_record(){
    if (!recording) {
       recording=true;
       // ................
       // ................
       // ................
       // your codes here
       // ................
       // ................
       // ................
       Sheduler_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override  public void run() { Restarter_Recording();  } }, RestartAfterSeconds * 1000);  //1000 ms is 1 second
    }
}

public void Restarter_Recording(){      if(!recording) return;
    // Stop now
    Stop_Record();
    //and Fire start immediately
    Sheduler_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { Start_Record(); } }, 100);
}
```

p.s. only minor gap is between video files, but for me it doesnt matter at this moment.